# Indices of the matched list items in LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to know the indices of the matched items in the LINQ query. I get an error in join when I try to get index. My code is as below and I am expecting (2, 0) for the first match and (3, 1) for the second match. I am new to LINQ and suggestions welcome.

```
public class Test
{
    public int a;
    public string b;

    public Test(int x, string y) { a = x; b = y; }
}        


    List<Test> a1= new List<Test>();  
    List<Test> b1= new List<Test>();  

    a1.Add(new Test(1, "test1-a"));
    a1.Add(new Test(2, "test2-a"));
    a1.Add(new Test(3, "test3-a"));
    a1.Add(new Test(4, "test4-a"));

    b1.Add(new Test(3, "test3-b"));
    b1.Add(new Test(4, "test4-b"));
    b1.Add(new Test(5, "test5-b"));
    b1.Add(new Test(6, "test6-b"));

    var x = from m in a1
            join n in b1 
            on m.a equals n.a
            select((index) => new { index, n.b });
```

Comment: Your expectations seem off, you're selecting b, which is a string, but expecting an integer

Comment: In fact, I need the indices of the list where the matches happen - (2,0) and (3,1) in this case. I would have used nested for loops but I am not sure where to break as I do not know where the match happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the overload of the `Select` method that also provides the index. But you need to do this before joining the collections. So it should look like this :

```
    var x =
            from m in a1.Select((r, ix) => new {Ix = ix, T = r})
            join n in b1.Select((r, ix) => new {Ix = ix, T = r}) 
             on m.T.a equals n.T.a
            select (m.Ix, n.Ix);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RUAEOk)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps in getting the indices.

Answer (score 2):

You can use overloaded `Select` version (which provides `item`s `index`) followed by `Join`:

```
var indexes = a1
  .Select((item, index) => (item, index))
  .Join(b1.Select((item, index) => (item, index)),
        pair => pair.item.a,
        pair => pair.item.a,
       (a, b) => (aIndex: a.index, bIndex: b.index));

// Let's have a look
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, indexes));
```

Output:

```
(2, 0)
(3, 1)
```